# Should links to files be added to questions?

Tags: discussion

In some cases, code is designed to be run with a file as input. These files have a particular format and so will to be relevant to how they are processed, as that dictates the structure of the file-reading code.

In particular, on my question: [Project Euler 81 (minimum path sum through a matrix)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60930/47450), I have added a link to the text file on the Project Euler site that is relevant to the question.

My only question is that should these links be added, even if they might contain dangerous content?

Comment: How about including the file's contents as part of the question, in a quoted code block with disabled code formatting?

Comment: Well in this case, it's a 81kb file, so it is rather large...

Comment: Related: [Should \[programming-challenge\] questions require a summary of the challenge?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993/9357)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should links to files be added to questions?

If it helps reviewers to review the code, it is preferable.

It is usually not required to make the question on-topic, but if the code/question is too hard to review without this file then vote to close as *unclear what you are asking*.

As for whether or not to embed it inside the question, that mostly depends on how big the file is and how important it is to the question.

> even if it might contain dangerous content

Don't link to dangerous content. Problem solved.